# How to get Entity and its properties and types using table name in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying read entity properties and their types using table name in EF6. for example

```
public partial class ContextEntities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<tblNote> tblNotes { get; set; }
}

public partial class tblNote
{
    public int intNoteID { get; set; }
    public string strLoanNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have entity name called `"tblNote"` in a string. by using this table name I want to get `tblNote` entity and its properties and types.

So I did like this

```
List<Reflection.PropertyInfo> props = new List<Reflection.PropertyInfo>();

PropertyInfo entityProperty = contextEntities.GetType().GetProperties().
                              Where(t => t.Name == "tblNote").Single();
if ((entityProperty != null))
    props.Add(entityProperty);
```

This is not working. I am only getting `contextEntities` properties.
How to do that?

Comment: If you want to get column schema information, for eg: `column size`, `data type` etc. *directly from the database*, checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330103/8644294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this query:

```
        var tblNoteProperties = contextEntities
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p =>
                p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
            .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .Where(t => t.Name == "tblNote")
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .ToArray();
```

Note, that model could be built dynamically, without declaring `DbSet<T>` properties on `DbContext`-derived type. In this case you should use EDM to explore entity types and their properties.

Comment: one of the tables name is `tbl_PriorityResults3.3.2014`, but Entity was created `tbl_PriorityResults3_3_2014`. Is there any way we get by using edmx xml store nname? `<EntitySet Name="tbl_DS_PriorityFilesAVMResults3_3_2014" EntityType="Self.tbl_Priority3_3_2014" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="tbl_PriorityResults3.3.2014">`?

Comment: The problem is that your question is clear, but your goal is not. Why don't you rename entity types and map them to appropriate tales? Neither `tblNote`, nor `tbl_DS_PriorityFilesAVMResults3_3_201` are not convenient type names to use from code.